# Creating webhooks in Kentico 13 Xperience

Tags: webhooks, kentico

My company uses Kentico 13 Xperience. I'm told we can create webhooks that can be referenced in Zapier to trigger certain automations. Specifically, I'm hoping to send bizform submissions DIRECTLY to Zapier, so we can farm them out to our various data and marketing tools from Zapier (we do this with other platforms we use, including LinkedIn forms).

The support documentation is sparse when it comes to creating webhooks... anyone here have a link to a reference for how to make these things?

I've scoured the existing Kentico 13 Xperience knowledge base site, and cannot find anything helpful. Hoping someone here can point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

From Kentico side of the thing I would use a [global event handler](https://docs.xperience.io/custom-development/handling-global-events) and handle the [bizform item events](https://docs.xperience.io/custom-development/handling-global-events/reference-global-system-events#ReferenceGlobalsystemevents-BizFormItemEvents). For example in the Insert After event, you can add your custom logic - e.g. the Zapier API and send the submitted item data wherever you want.